# Mod rewrite with anchor

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, anchor

I have this   addrress
    http://mysite.com/index.php?cat=7

I write this mod rewrite

```
 RewriteRule ^category/(\d+) index.php?cat=$1
```

this means: if someone opens my adrress, his automatically he goes to the address:

```
  http://mysite.com/category/7
```

but i need use anchor also, that is, i need at the opening my address, happened redirected to this address:

```
 http://mysite.com/category/7#!somesome
```

Tell me please, how to write such RewriteRule  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you want to acquire the URL fragment (the part of the URL after the #) using (Apache's) mod rewrite.

Unfortunately this cannot be done. According to [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier):

> The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the URI: namely, its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from the server

and

> When an agent (such as a Web browser) requests a resource from a Web server, the agent sends the URI to the server, but does not send the fragment.

You'll have to work around this issue, probably using (client-side) javascript.

Comment: yup, when you see websites such as google translate using hash string to maintain context, this is so that a javascript in one invocation can pass context to its equivalent in the next.  The client-side javascript can see this.  It doesn't even get sent to the server